# Macro representing maximum value for uint64_t

Tags: c++, uint64

I'm seeking for a macro representing the maximum value of `uint64_t` as `UINT_MAX` is for `unsigned int`.
i.e. I need this value to guaranteed to be (1<<64)-1.

I tried to use `UINT64_MAX`, but compiling with g++ results in:

```
'UINT64_MAX' was not declared in this scope
```

It's worth to mention that I have this line `#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` in the code before using `UINT64_MAX`.

I was surprised to not find helpful information around the web about it.

Comment: idk what `#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` is, but you probably want it before the includes, not before use of `UINTwhatever`

Comment: C++11 implementations ship with `cstdint` which provides `UINT64_MAX`. Boost also provides an implementation of this header, if it is available to you.

Comment: Why macro in c++? Doesn't `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` work?

Comment: @IgorR. I thought the same, but there is no hard requirement on an implementation to provide a `numeric_limits` specialization for those types, although chances are good that there is one. Although, `max()` is less useful without `constexpr`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, correct. I have it before the relevant include.

Comment: @pmr, I'm linked with the Boost libraries. Do you know to specify the macro/constant that I need?

Comment: @IgorR, `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` did the trick. Thanks. You can put it as an answer if you want to.

Comment: @pmr The Standard requires `numeric_limit::max()` to be `constexpr`. But you're right in that some popular implementations are non-conforming.

Comment: @IgorR. Yes, I'm not sure which compilers OP wants to support and this has a large bearing on those answers. I tried reflecting that in my answer.

Comment: There's always `#ifndef UINT64_MAX    #define UINT64_MAX 18446744073709551615`   , with the relevant suffix (if `ull` is not supported, then perhaps `ui64`)

Comment: Or `#define UINT64_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using the `cstdint` header portably can be quite a challenge (it is missing from some MSVC implementations). At the same time `numeric_limits::max()` can be hard to use without `constexpr` and it is not actually required to work with `uint64_t`. If you don't care about those things too much, `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` will most likely do the trick.

[Boost.Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/integer/doc/html/index.html) has an implementation of `cstdint` and comes with an extra traits class to get a constant maximal value. A compliant implementation of `cstdint` should also provide the macro `UINT64_MAX`, but I'm not sure about boost.

Comment: I second boost integer. It's header only I believe and can be used anywhere on most any compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just curious why isn't there a macro for it as UINT_MAX, to save the function call?

Comment: @Subway There is no function call with numeric_limits in C++11, because max is constexpr.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't use C++11 :(

Comment: @Subway So, you really want the Boost.Integer library.

Comment: The thing is, I coudln't find any appropriate constant there.

Comment: @Subway [boost::integer_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/traits.html) has a member `const_max`

Comment: how can i do it without boost  .

Comment: @BhawinParkeria If you have C++11, try `numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 0):

While including the header `<limits>` and calling `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` will solve the question,

here is the simplest way of actual implementation using **typecasting**, in case that you don't remember the spelling of `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`. (Amnesia can actually happen to all of you! ...at some point in the past or in the future...)

- Note: The usability of this method depends on *how your language version treats the negative value*. The "two's complement" is the issue around 2023... but you have to try this once, if you haven't tried.

It writes:

```
uint64_t(-1)  // functional notation
```

or

```
(uint64_t)-1   // c-like cast notation
```

For example, you can print the exact value of its max number like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "max value = " << uint64_t(-1);
}
```

and the result of output is:

```
max value = 18446744073709551615
```

Voilà!

==== further reading below ====

Indeed, many compiler headers use this kind of typecasting as the value of those pre-defined "limits" macro. For example, in my macOS dev environment with XCode and g++, my C++ header file limits.h says, inside the `template <class _Type, bool = is_arithmetic<_Type>::value> class __libcpp_numeric_limits`:

```
static constexpr const bool is_signed = _Type(-1) < _Type(0);
```

it's a clever way of checking the signed-unsigned type. And then,

```
static constexpr const _Type __min = __libcpp_compute_min<_Type, digits, is_signed>::value;
static constexpr const _Type __max = is_signed ? _Type(_Type(~0) ^ __min) : _Type(~0);
```

the min uses the calculation that involves a special template, while the max uses is_signed result. The min template is:

```
template <class _Type, int __digits, bool _IsSigned>
struct __libcpp_compute_min {
    static constexpr const _Type value = _Type(_Type(1) << __digits);
};
```

which looks similar to your expression in your question `(1<<64)-1` except the `-1` part.

Try checking the limits headers in your own computer and see what it says!

Comment: You might want to mention that this depends on C++23, which is the first C++ to mandate 2's-complement representation for signed integers.

Comment: I have inserted a note according to your comment, @TobySpeight. Thank you!